# PHP how to get the last item count in "showing # of # items" on a page

Tags: php, pagination, e-commerce

I am making a products page and beside my pagination I want to show the item counts per page.

So something like "Showing 1 - 10 products".

I figured out how to calculate the first item number, but I am stuck with figuring out the last # of items on the page.

So assuming I have 10 items per page and 35 items in total the first page would show "1 - 10" the next page would show "11 - 20"  and  the next "21 - 30" and the last page would show "31 - 35".

```
<?php
//connect to the database
include_once ('includes/connect_to_mysql.php'); 
    $category = urldecode ($_GET["cat"]); // get category for the current page from the URL
    $page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
    $limit = 10;
    $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
    $statement = "products WHERE active = 1 AND category = '$category'";
?>
<header>
    <div class="paging">
        Page: &nbsp; <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE active = 1 AND category = '$category'"; 
        $rs_result = mysql_query($sql); //run the query
        $total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  //count number of records
        $num_rec_per_page = 10; //number of records per page
        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 

        for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo '<a href="categories.php?cat='.urlencode($category).'&page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;';
            };

        $first = ($page * $limit) - $limit +1;
        $last = 'NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE';
?>
    </div>
    <form action="#" >
    <select onchange="javascript:addSort();" name="sortBy" id="sortBy">
        <option value="">Default</option>
        <option value="PriceHiLo">Price (High to Low)</option>
        <option value="PriceLoHi">Price (Low to High)</option>
        <option value="pID">Most Recent</option>
    </select> &nbsp; Showing <?php echo $first?> - <?php echo $last?> of <?php echo $total_records?> Product(s)
    </form>
</header>
```

Any help with figuring out how to calculate $last in the above code would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I believe that in the last page, the `$last` variable should hold the num_rows results, which is `$total_records`. For all the other cases use `$first + $num_rec_per_page`

Comment: You don't have `$limit` or `$page` defined anywhere in this script (which is used in `$first`)

Comment: On a side note - become familiar with mysqli as soon as possible, it's much newer and safer than mysql.

Comment: That doesn't work because on the last page when there is an uneven amount of products it will show "21 - 30" instead of "21-35".

Comment: Apologies added the code for $limit and $page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I needed an if statement:

```
            if ($total_records > ($page * $limit)){
            $last = ($page * $limit);
            } else {
                $last = $total_records;
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Without if case

```
floor(total / perPageSize) + (total % perPageSize)
```